# Protobuf C# generates internal (versus public) constructor

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

For some reason the generated code contains internal constructor instead of public constructor:

```
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
    internal MyProtobufMessage()
    {
        OnConstruction();
    }
```

From the [official document](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated), it is supposed to be public:

```
  // Parameterless constructor which calls the OnConstruction partial method if provided.
  public Foo();
```

I am wondering if there's any option that I can specify to generate a public constructor. I need it to be public because I am using generic template which requires the type to have a public constructor (new() constraint).

Protobuf version I am using: 3.11.4

The .proto file is something like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "timestamp.proto";

package MyNamespace;
option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace";

message MyProtobufMessage{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I removed the protobuf-net tag because you're using the Google tools, not protobuf-net. That said: protobuf-net loves and embraces public parameterless constructors! You can run your schema through https://protogen.marcgravell.com to see what it wants here.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to make the whole message classes internal, but AFAIK there should always be a public parameterless constructor.

Do you know exactly how your `.protos` file is being compiled?

N.B. that the code generation is done by a separate package `Google.Protobuf.tools` - you should check this package is also at 3.11.4 (and that your .proto compile is picking the latest version of `protoc`).

The compilation process should be a command similar to:
`C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\Google.Protobuf.tools\3.11.4\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe .\test.proto --csharp_out .\`